# Numbering a multiline environment

Tags: numbering, arrays

How can i number a multiline environment (such as array rather than equation) so that the numbering is placed bottom right? [image: this is what i am trying to achieve]

this is the part of the code in document which would give result as on the picture but without the numbering (1.1.8)

```
$
\begin{array}{lll}  
\displaystyle\max_{x} & \sum\limits_{j=1}^n\ (\textstyle\sum_{p=1}^P c_{p}C_{pj})x_{j}\   &  \textnormal{[profit to be maximized]}  \\  
\textnormal{subject to} & &  \\
 & \sum\limits_{j=1}^n A_{rj}x_{j}\leq b_{r},  1\leq r\leq R & \textnormal{[upper bounds on consumed resources should be met]}  \\
 & \sum\limits_{j=1}^n C_{pj}x_{j}\geq d_{r},  1\leq p\leq P & \textnormal{[lower bounds on products' yield should be met]} \\
 & \left.
\begin{array}{ll}
\sum\limits_{j=1}^n x_{j}\leq 1 \\
x_{j}\geq 0, 1\leq j \leq n
\end{array}\right\} 
&
\left[
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{total intensity should be } \leq 1 \text{ and} \\
\text{intensities must be nonnegative}
\end{array}\right] 
\end{array}
$
```

Comment: This is a standard behaviour when some lines (here, e.g., this with `[lower bounds...` are too long.

Comment: please add a minimal exemple of your code and explain `so that the numbering is placed bottom right?`

Comment: @touhami i added a part of the code, and the numbering that is supposed to be placed bottom right means under the set of arrays/equations as in the picture (numbering meaning (1.1.8))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure i understood the question
you want

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{equation}{section}
\renewcommand\theequation{\thesection.\@arabic\c@equation}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\section{Foo bar}
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{lll}  
\displaystyle\max_{x} & \sum\limits_{j=1}^n\ (\textstyle\sum_{p=1}^P c_{p}C_{pj})x_{j}\   &  \textnormal{[profit to be maximized]}  \\  
\textnormal{subject to} & &  \\
 & \sum\limits_{j=1}^n A_{rj}x_{j}\leq b_{r},  1\leq r\leq R & \textnormal{[upper bounds on consumed resources should be met]}  \\
 & \sum\limits_{j=1}^n C_{pj}x_{j}\geq d_{r},  1\leq p\leq P & \textnormal{[lower bounds on products' yield should be met]} \\
 & \left.
\begin{array}{ll}
\sum\limits_{j=1}^n x_{j}\leq 1 \\
x_{j}\geq 0, 1\leq j \leq n
\end{array}\right\} 
&
\left[
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{total intensity should be } \leq 1 \text{ and} \\
\text{intensities must be nonnegative}
\end{array}\right] 
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

this is normal when the formula is larger than the text width.

I think that you want this every time you have a multiline equation no?
Note that what you do is not the good way to format multilines equations please see [amsmath documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{equation}{section}
\renewcommand\theequation{\thesection.\@arabic\c@equation}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\section{Foo bar}   

\begin{align*}
x& = y_1-y_2+y_3-y_5+y_8-\dots
&& \text{total intensity should be}\\
& = y'\circ y^* && \text{total intensity}\\
& = y(0) y' && \text {total} \\
& && \refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Finally here is you example using `align*`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{equation}{section}
\renewcommand\theequation{\thesection.\@arabic\c@equation}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\section{Foo bar}

\begin{align*} 
&\max_{x}
&  
& \sum\limits_{j=1}^n\ (\textstyle\sum_{p=1}^P c_{p}C_{pj})x_{j}
& 
&\textnormal{[profit to be maximized]}  \\  
&\textnormal{subject to} 
& 
&
&
&\\
&
& 
&\sum\limits_{j=1}^n A_{rj}x_{j}\leq b_{r},  1\leq r\leq R 
&
& \textnormal{[upper bounds on consumed resources should be met]}  \\
&
& 
&\sum\limits_{j=1}^n C_{pj}x_{j}\geq d_{r},  1\leq p\leq P 
&
& \textnormal{[lower bounds on products' yield should be met]} \\
& 
&
&\left.
\begin{array}{ll}
\sum\limits_{j=1}^n x_{j}\leq 1 \\
x_{j}\geq 0, 1\leq j \leq n
\end{array}\right\} 
&
&
\left[
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{total intensity should be } \leq 1 \text{ and} \\
\text{intensities must be nonnegative}
\end{array}\right] \\
& & & &  & \refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you :) i didn't know the equation one will send it into a new line, usually it would just set the number next to it, that is exactly what i needed :)